# webshare API multiple instances on same page

Tags: javascript, for-loop, web-share

Hopefuly someone can assist/direct me here.

I'm making use of the webshare API on my site. The site contains an array of posts that will have a share link. This is built using a foreach and all have unique urls to use. I want to add a share button to each of those images. I currently have it working on a singular instance but unable to get it to loop through all the share buttons.

Here is the current script:

```
const shareButton = document.querySelector('.share-button');
const url = document.querySelector('.post-link a').href;

shareButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (navigator.share) { 
   navigator.share({
      title: 'Check out this ad I saw on ...',
      url
    }).then(() => {
      console.log('Shared');
    })
    .catch(console.error);
    }
});
```

I'm really struggling with how to get it to loop through all share buttons and not just be usable on the first instance.

Apologeis if this is simple.

Answer (score 0):

For a start, you need to add a click listener to *all* buttons, not just the first. You can do this exclusively when the API is supported, else, you may want to hide the buttons. Here's the modified script (note that you need to get the URL of each post individually, see the comment):

```js
const shareButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.share-button');

if ('share' in navigator) {  
  shareButtons.forEach((shareButton) => {
    shareButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      // Get the URL from the dataset or query the DOM.  
      const url = shareButton.dataset(url); 
      navigator.share({
        title: 'Check out this ad I saw on ...',
        url
      }).then(() => {
        console.log('Shared');
      }).catch(console.error);
    });
  });
} else {
  shareButtons.forEach((shareButton) => {
    shareButton.style.display = 'none';
  });
}
```